# How to enable Chiral Scroll on touchpad in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

I have HP laptop which have 2 drivers related to touchpad/mouse - ELAN PrecisionTouchpad and ELAN Input Device.
Changing anything with ELAN Input Device don't affect touchpad, even after disabling it touchpad work. Installing wrong driver in place of PrecisionTouchpad or disabling it, leave the touchpad not working, so have to install the default one again. So, I think PrecisionTouchpad is main driver.

I want to use Chiral Scroll (see video on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUFxeZz7qvw to see what it is). It is very convenient for scrolling through long documents or browsing, than two-finger scroll.

It is available on Synaptics PS/2 touchpad driver but PS/2 drivers don't install over Precision driver.

I want to know if there is a way to enable Chiral Scroll?
Either by installing the PS/2 driver or by using some 3rd party tool or some other way.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try in registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPadDisplay` to set the DWORD value `EdgeScroll_Display` to `1`. If it works, the option should appear in the mouse Properties.

Comment: @harrymc There are no seperate settings for the touchpad. I can change  settings for touchpad only using Window's inbuilt Settings.

Comment: You mean this registry key doesn't exist? In this case I think you only have the Windows generic driver. You can verify the driver in the Device Manager.

Comment: @harrymc that value is already set to 1. I am saying that there are only standard windows settings to configure touchpad, like 2, 3 and 4 fingure gestures in 'Windows Settings>Devices>Touchpad'. There are no seperate settings.

Comment: In *Control Panel > Mouse*, do you have an ELAN tab? If you do, what do you have in Options?

Comment: @harrymc There is no ELAN tab, with precision drivers that tab don't come, thats the issue. Thats why I was trying to install ps/2 driver.

Comment: (1) Do you have the program `C:\Program Files\Elantech\ETDAniConf.exe`, if yes try it. (2) You might try [this driver](https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/KEYBOARD-and-MOUSE/Elantech/HP-Pavilion-15-dq1000-x360-Elantech-Touchpad-Driver-22-2-15-1-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml), which isn't PS2. (3) This [webpage](https://blog.jtbworld.com/2013/10/how-to-disable-edge-swipe-by-showing.html) might be relevant.

Comment: @harrymc Please read the first para of the description again, I added some details. 1) ETDAniConf.exe is associated with a driver which don't install over PrecisionTouchpad, but over Input Device, and even with that give errors. Still tried it and the changing settings in app don't change anything. 2) This driver is the 'ELAN Input Device'. 3) Uses the driver which had file 'ETDAniConf.exe' file, still tried adding the reg files, but still changing settings in that window don't change anything.

Comment: What are the exact models of your computer and touchpad?

Comment: @harrymc Touchpad is ETD0718 in HP Pavillion, There are 4 drivers with same hardware id (different 'Col'), 2 of them are the drivers I mentioned above

Comment: What is your driver in Device Manager, Properties, regarding manufacturer and version?

Comment: @harrymc ELAN Input Device - Manufacturer: Elan - v22.2.23.2;  
ELAN PrecisionTouchpad Filter Driver - Manufacturer: Elan - v22.2.22.4;  
ELAN HID Class Filter Driver - Manufacturer: Elan HID Device - v22.2.21.2;  
I2C HID Device - Manufacturer: Microsoft - 10.0.19041

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you delete the device & driver and reboot to let Microsoft install its driver. The process of deletion is described [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/installing-updated-elan-track-pad-drivers-for-y510p.751866/) (ignore the rest).

Comment: @harrymc it installs Microsoft's driver, already tried. Thanks for still trying to help.

Comment: Microsoft's precision driver can't do that?

Comment: @harrymc Name of driver is HID Compliant touch pad. There are no exclusive settings for it too, only the options that are available in Windows Settings. (same for both ELAN's precision and MS's HID Compliant)

Comment: Last try: Read the advice in [this post]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/elan-smart-pad-settings-gone-after-windows-10/00d9feb1-c15c-4dc8-be3e-01490ddb45d4?auth=1&page=1). You might need to install the older driver version that is mentioned, requiring a careful delete of the existing driver.

Comment: @harrymc  I went through all four pages, new thing I found was installing driver in compatibility mode, even though all drivers I have tried installing did install, but still I tried installing them in compatibilty mode, but still no improvement. Reason is there is no driver which can install over the Precision driver, all the drivers I install, install over ELAN input device, which don't affect touchpad, as even with ELAN Input Device 'Diabled', touchpad work. Main driver is the Precision Driver for which I can't find alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written an application that implements chiral scrolling using the Windows Precision Touchpad driver. It should (in theory) work on any modern Windows laptop. Let me know if you have any issues with it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/chiralscroll/

Comment: It works like a charm. It's amazing. Thanks.